# C# Winforms Treeview Customized Checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm working on a utility that helps me construct long, repetitive HTML tables.  I have data imported from an XML file, a listBox that shows the names, buttons that insert text into a richTextBox that contains certain data from the XML, but there's info I have to enter manually for each name.

I have a treeView that lists committees ( parent ) and subcommittees ( 1 level of children ).  I can check the appropriate boxes, click a button, and all the corresponding HTML is created.  However, each committee ( and sub ) has a chairperson and a ranking member.  Instead of adding those two extra nodes under each parent and child - I have 71 parents and children.  I'd rather not add 142 more nodes -  I'm hoping there's a way to have "four-click" checkboxes...?  1st click = checkmark; 2nd = green; 3rd = red; 4th = cleared.  Or similar.  That way I could "check" for being a member, "double-check" for Chair, "triple-check" for Ranking, and a fourth would just start over.

I'm open to suggestions for another approach, as well.  This is the last bit I need to get working to save me typing 2-3K lines of HTML by hand, so I don't care how I get it done.  Thanks.

Comment: Just use the NodeMouseClick event and a counter.  Reset the counter when the AfterSelect event.  You'll need to work around a bug with [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3174824/17034).

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [this appoach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644011/how-to-show-multiple-check-boxes-in-a-treeview-in-c/28654034?s=5|0.2268#28654034), using extra checkboxes. Adapting it to tri-state shouldn't be too hard either..

Comment: Can you upload an image, I would like to help you but I don't understand so much what you said.

Comment: Taw - I like that approach, however, I followed the link after the other answer which turned me on to the StateImageList.  So I'm thinking I can modify that and use Hans' idea of click event/counter to display the appropriate image.  I'll report back in a bit.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sorry it's been a while.  You know, life and such.  Anyway, I ended up my own TreeNode and TreeView classes.  This is my first adventure with WinForms, so a lot of this seemed quite finicky.  Ended up be much simpler than I had imagined.  If anybody wants to use this, knock yourself out.

The Check*.bmp images are just a checked box that I colored in.  I'll probably make my own four images for this and neaten up the populateStateImageList() method.  Also, I would think this would work for as many states as you need, up to the 14 image limit of StateImageList.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace jkHTMLBuilder
{
    public class QuadCheckTreeNode : TreeNode
    {
        public enum CheckState : int { UnChecked, Checked, Chair, Rank }    // The four possible states
        private CheckState _cs = CheckState.UnChecked;                      // The node's current state

        public CheckState checkState
        {
            get
            {
                return _cs;
            }
            set
            {
                _cs = value;
            }
        }

        public QuadCheckTreeNode(string initString) : base()
        {
            this.Text = initString;
            this.checkState = CheckState.UnChecked;
            this.Checked = false;
            this.StateImageIndex = 0;
        }

        public void checkAdvance()                                          // This is called from onAfterCheck to set the next consecutive state
        {
            switch (checkState)
            {
                case CheckState.UnChecked:
                    checkState = CheckState.Checked;
                    break;
                case CheckState.Checked:
                    checkState = CheckState.Chair;
                    break;
                case CheckState.Chair:
                    checkState = CheckState.Rank;
                    break;
                case CheckState.Rank:
                    checkState = CheckState.UnChecked;
                    break;
            }

            this.Checked = (this.checkState == CheckState.UnChecked ? false : true);
        }
    }

    class QuadCheckTreeView : TreeView
    {
        private bool clickStop = false;
        private bool shouldAdvance = false;
        public QuadCheckTreeView() : base()
        {
            StateImageList = new ImageList();
        }

        public void populateStateImageList()                                // I made this a separate method and call it from my Load_Senators method so the images are
        {                                                                   // set up when the XML file is loaded.  Apparently, loading the files ( Check*.bmmp )
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)                                     // from the ctor causes problems...?  Whatever.  This works.
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(16, 16);
                Graphics chkGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(chkGraphics, new Point(0, 1), System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(chkGraphics, new Point(0, 1), System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal);
                        break;
                }

                StateImageList.Images.Add(bmp);
            }
            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("..\\..\\CheckBlue.bmp");
            StateImageList.Images.Add(myBitmap);
            myBitmap = new Bitmap("..\\..\\CheckRed.bmp");
            StateImageList.Images.Add(myBitmap);
        }                               

        public void ClearNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)                    // This is for when I move on to the next record.  Unchecks everything.
        {
            clickStop = true;
            foreach (QuadCheckTreeNode qctn in nodes)
            {
                qctn.Checked = false;
                qctn.checkState = QuadCheckTreeNode.CheckState.UnChecked;
                if (qctn.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (QuadCheckTreeNode cqctn in qctn.Nodes)
                    {
                        cqctn.Checked = false;
                        cqctn.checkState = QuadCheckTreeNode.CheckState.UnChecked;
                    }
                }
            }
            clickStop = false;
        }

        protected override void OnCreateControl()
        {
            base.OnCreateControl();
            CheckBoxes = false;                                             // Checkboxes off to use my images
            ClearNodes(this.Nodes);                                         // Probably not needed.
        }

        protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNodeMouseClick(e);

            TreeViewHitTestInfo tvhtInfo = HitTest(e.X, e.Y);               // If you didn't click on it, ignore.
            if (tvhtInfo == null || tvhtInfo.Location !=
            TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage)
            {
                return;
            }

            QuadCheckTreeNode qctn = (QuadCheckTreeNode)e.Node;             // If you right-clicked, set to UnChecked
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                if (qctn.checkState != QuadCheckTreeNode.CheckState.UnChecked)
                {
                    qctn.checkState = QuadCheckTreeNode.CheckState.UnChecked;
                    qctn.Checked = false;
                    shouldAdvance = false;
                }
            }
            else
                shouldAdvance = true;                                       // Left click sets this var==true so the node's Advance() method is called

            qctn.Checked = qctn.Checked;                                    // This fires the onAfterCheck event
        }

        protected override void OnAfterCheck(TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnAfterCheck(e);

            if (clickStop)                                                  // This keeps the event from running if it's called inappropriately
            {
                return;
            }

            clickStop = true;

            QuadCheckTreeNode qctn = (QuadCheckTreeNode)e.Node;
            if (shouldAdvance)
            {
                qctn.checkAdvance();
                shouldAdvance = false;
                qctn.StateImageIndex = (int)qctn.checkState;
            }

            checkParent(qctn);                                              // Calling this method, if it actually checks a parent node, won't call onAfterCheck because of clickStop

            clickStop = false;
        }

        protected void checkParent(QuadCheckTreeNode qctn)
        {
            QuadCheckTreeNode pqctn = (QuadCheckTreeNode)qctn.Parent;
            if (pqctn == null)
                return;
            if (pqctn.checkState == QuadCheckTreeNode.CheckState.UnChecked) // This checks a parent if it has a checked child
            {
                bool chkParent = false;

                foreach (QuadCheckTreeNode n in pqctn.Nodes)
                {
                    if (n.checkState != QuadCheckTreeNode.CheckState.UnChecked)     // Checks all the children.  If even one is checked, the parent gets checked
                        chkParent = true;
                }
                if (chkParent)
                {
                    pqctn.Checked = true;
                    pqctn.checkState = QuadCheckTreeNode.CheckState.Checked;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```